# Are there open databases or sites similar to xssed.com, not necessarily about XSS?

Tags: databases, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities

Are there open databases, websites similar to [xssed.com](http://xssed.com) that are not necessarily about XSS, but where people report SQL inject-able websites or malware infected websites, for example?

*Potentially with an Application Programming Interface (API)?*

Comment: For malware infected sites, there are [Google Safe Browsing](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [xssposed.org](https://www.xssposed.org), a successor website for [xssed.com](http://xssed.com) (actually they imported the old xssed database), and which was renamed to [Open Bug Bounty](https://www.openbugbounty.org/) a few months ago.

They list XSS and open redirects.

Comment: @EvanderConsus that's very interesting. My records indicate that it used to be listed on https://www.xssposed.org/incidents/13038/ However, it is now a 404.

Comment: @EvanderConsus not at all, but I did watch it in order to notify (certain) affected people.

Comment: No, I didn't. Feel free to do so. Although when I contacted them once long ago but didn't get any reply… They seem to have botched with an update.

Comment: @EvanderConsus tell me if you get a reply :)